# How to assign values to a reducer with an initialState with two objects?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have the following reducer below for user's submitting a rating and getting the user's ratings (your_ratings)...

When `LOAD_YOURRATINGS_SUCCESS` occurs, the two levels of initalState are being remove, and `your_ratings` is becoming the value of `store.rating`, when I want it to be `store.rating.your_ratings`.

What am I doing wrong below? Thanks

```
import * as types from '../actions/actionTypes';

const initialState = {
  rating: {},
  your_ratings: {}
}

export default function ratingReducer(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case types.CREATE_RATING_SUCCESS:
      return action.rating
    case types.LOAD_YOURRATINGS_SUCCESS:
      return action.your_ratings
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to update your state and not overwrite it, you can do it with the help of spread operator like

```
export default function ratingReducer(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case types.CREATE_RATING_SUCCESS:
      return {...state, rating: action.rating}
    case types.LOAD_YOURRATINGS_SUCCESS:
      return {...state, your_ratings: action.your_ratings}
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I will mark correct as soon as I am allowed

Comment: There is also alternative option to use combined reducers, so you can have two reducers - one for `rating`, second for `your_rating` and you can combine them to single `ratingReducer` with redux combine

Comment: @Jurosh, They both relate to the same functionality, why would you separate them. I think the current configuration is the correct

Comment: Jurosh's suggestion is also a good one.  Just as the root reducer can delegate the work of a slice like `state.ratings` to the `ratingReducer` function, `ratingReducer` could itself delegate the work of updating its two slices to a `yourRatingsReducer` and a `allRatingsReducer`.